# objShell error, and Shutdown

Tags: vbscript

When I try to open this I get this error:

> 'objShell 800A01A8'

I have no clue what it is, but it is quite annoying as it worked just before. Here is my code:

```
WScript.Sleep 0
Const wshYes = 6 
Const wshNo = 7 
Const wshYesNoDialog = 4 
Const wshQuestionMark = 32 
intReturn = objShell.Popup("Vil du annulere shutdown?", _ 
    20, "Shutdown om 5 minutter!", wshYesNoDialog + wshQuestionMark) 
If intReturn = wshYes Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Shutdown annuleret." 
    objShell.Run "C:\ProgramData\AutoShutdown\Annuler.bat" 
End If
```

Basically I want this to be executed 5 minutes before scheduled/planned Shutdown, asking if you want to cancel (cancel=annuller) the shutdown.

This is where I have another problem though, it basically has to execute `shutdown -a`, but as I am *very* bad at VBScript, I failed. Currently making the VBScript open a batch file simply doing `shutdpwn -a` if user chooses "Yes".

So, I would ***really*** appriciate it if anyone would tell me how to:

- Make the file work.
- Make the VBScript itself run the `shutdown -a` if "yes" is the option.

Comment: If this is all the code, you have not initialized `objShell` to a `WScript.Shell` instance.

Comment: This means you are using a variable `objShell` that has not been initialized. You are missing something like `Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

Comment: Haha, thanks xD That's the answer I was looking for :P

Comment: Got any clue how to do the second thing? :)

Comment: Once you have the variable properly initialized the `Run` method will work. Just use `objShell.Run "cmd.exe /c ""C:\ProgramData\AutoShutdown\Annuler.bat"""` to call your batch file or directly `objShell.Run "shutdown.exe -a"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get inspired of this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,ws,N,Question 
Titre = "Arrêt automatique de l'ordinateur"
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Do
    Call Choisir()
    Call Poser_question()
Loop

Sub Choisir()
    Do 
        N  = Trim(InputBox("Taper le nombre de secondes avant shutdown : ",Titre,"60")) 
        If Not IsNumeric(N)  Then
            ws.Popup "Vous devez taper un Nombre !","3",Titre,0+48
        End if
    Loop Until IsNumeric(N) 
    MsgBox "Vous avez choisi " & N & " seconde(s) avant le shutdown de votre PC !",64,Titre
    Run_Shutdown(N) 
End Sub

Sub Poser_question()
    Question = MsgBox ("Vouliez-vous annuler le shutdown de votre PC ?",VBYesNO+VbQuestion,Titre)
    If Question = VbYes then
        Call Annuler_Shutdown()
        Wscript.Quit
    else
        Wscript.Quit    
    end if
End Sub

Sub Run_Shutdown(N)
    Dim Command,Execution
    Command = "Cmd /c Shutdown -s -t "& N &" -c "& DblQuote("Sauvegarder votre travail car votre PC va s'arrêter dans "& N &" seconde(s)")
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End sub

Sub Annuler_Shutdown()
    Dim Command,Execution
    Command = "Cmd /c Shutdown -a"
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End Sub

'*****************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter des guillemets dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*****************************************************************
```